# Вложенные отчёты

Tags: c#

На этом рисунке то, что должно быть:

[image]

На этом рисунке то, что есть:

[image]

Отчёт делаю на C# (rdlc).

Как сделать недостающую часть? Пытался объединить три ячейки (123+123+правее) и вставить на их место вложенный отчёт.

Написал запрос к базе данных, который вычисляет нужные данные. Запрос параметрический: содержит номер обогатительной фабрики и отчётный месяц. На вложенный отчёт добавил таблицу, отображающую требуемые данные.

Как передать параметры из основного отчёта во вложенный? Какие есть другие способы создания такого отчёта?

Comment: (Я не спец по RDLC, но:) Нельзя ли сделать неким образом виртуальную строчку данных? Например, написать wrapper реального источника данных и добавить недостающее? Данные вычислить заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи параметров во вложенный отчёт следует воспользоваться событием SubreportProcessing. В студии есть небольшой глюк, и с помощью визуального редактора не добавить обработчик этого события, поэтому нужно действовать руками.

```
public frmReport()
{
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += MySubreportHandler;
}
void MySubreportHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    //здесь e содержит некоторые параметры вложенного отчёта.
    var p1 = e.Parameters[0].Values[0];//Так извлекаются параметры, которые переданы из родительского отчёта во вложенный. Они задаются в конструкторе отчётов в свойствах вложенного отчёта.
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", getDataTable(p1));
}
```